# Open Settings Programmatically

Tags: angularjs, gps, ionic-framework

I have to develop an app with ionic framework, that get my Position using gps. When GPS or internet connection is disable, I have to put an alert that warn the user that GPS or internet connection is disable, and when user press "OK" button, device's settings open automatically. There is some plugin for ionic or angularjs to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Cordova-open-native-settings](https://github.com/selahssea/Cordova-open-native-settings) whose allow you to open Location Settings view from Android Cordova application and to open Native App settings view from iOS 8 Cordova application.

Comment: How can I do that when I go to the setting the app stop, and when I return on my app, the app restart with the main function?